# Remove the 0 from for results

Tags: php

Currently, I'm messing around with SoundCloud's API and it's returning something that looks like this.

```
0. HotBox Michael da Vinci Prod Free P.mp3
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/373337717/stream?client_id=OURID

1. LSSR Chris P Prod Jake Knight.mp3
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/373336760/stream?client_id=OURID
```

Which is working properly as how the code appears, here it is how I'm printing out the results (very messy but I'm just messing around)

```
for ($i = 0; isset($house[$i]); $i++) {
    $b1 = $house[$i]['title'];
    $b2 = $house[$i]['stream_url'];
    print '<br>';   print '<br>';
    $title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strip_tags($b1));
    print ''.$i.'. '.$title.'.mp3';
    print '<br>';
    print $stream = ''.$b2.'?client_id=OURID';
}
```

Now what I'm wondering is how under every circumstance can we make the `0.` return as a `1.` and continue counting upwards until reaching the end of the for loop, not removing the `0.` data but only changing the number.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, because it's not the API printing out 0, 1, etc. It's *your* code. You're printing out your loop number. Can't you just add 1 to that when you print?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I think he's asking to make the loop start at 1 within the loop.. which is kinda confusing

Comment: @Herbo Yeah... making the loop start at 1 doesn't make any sense - the OP is reading from an array, which would be 0-based.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I understand what he's trying to do but not sure how I'd execute it either.. Pretty sure he's using the `$i` string to indicate the track number within a playlist, as he's returned two results. Playlist normally start at `1` so he's trying to find an alternative to using `$i` I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a foreach loop with the $i counter declared in the loop and just increment it as you go.

Untested code:

```
foreach ($house as $i=>$row){
    echo '<br><br>',++$i,'. ',preg_replace ('/[^a-z\d\s]+/i','',strip_tags ($row ['title'])),".mp3<br>{$row ['stream_url']}?client_id=OURID";
}
```

p.s. I've improved the regex pattern and eliminated all single-use variable declarations.  You can break this up over many lines if you prefer.

If you want to avoid the first iteration's double break tags...

```
foreach ($house as $i=>$row){
    if($i) echo '<br><br>';  // if $i is not 0
    echo ++$i,'. ';
    echo preg_replace ('/[^a-z\d\s]+/i','',strip_tags ($row ['title']));
    echo ".mp3<br>{$row ['stream_url']}?client_id=OURID";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and your description of what you are trying to do, it sounds like you just need to add another iteration variable:

```
# Add another variable
$a = 1;
for ($i = 0; isset($house[$i]); $i++) {
    $b1 = $house[$i]['title'];
    $b2 = $house[$i]['stream_url'];
    $title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strip_tags($b1));
    echo '<br><br>';
    # Here you have the $a show up starting at 1
    echo ''.$a.'. '.$title.'.mp3<br>';
    echo $stream = ''.$b2.'?client_id=OURID';
    # Auto increment here
    $a++;
}
```